# How to get/generate the token for raw url for a image file in a private repo (Bitbucket)?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

When I click on raw url of a image in my **private** repo, it redirects to `bytebucket.org` & append a token so that it can be viewed publicly.These urls look something like this:

https://bytebucket.org/**$username**/**$repo**/raw/**$sha**/$filename.jpg?token=`$sometoken`.

I figured that these tokens are unique for each file. Is there any way I can get/generate this type of `token` through bitbucket api?

Comment: Probably this issue: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/8784/public-url-on-private-repositories-bb-9955